# MySQL standalone or via XAMPP?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

This is my first question ever at stackoverflow, hope I make sense out of it. I am starting to learn about databases and also programming these days. So I would want to get some advice on MySQL database. Though it's open source and available for download, Should I install the standalone MySQL GUI version on my laptop (Windows 7 32bit) or should I install XAMPP and then access it through phpMyAdmin ?? My purpose of asking this question is that , for starters..I am learning SQL and querying. And then I would want to learn to create web application using php or JavaEE.
I am completely unaware of these concepts, so I would appreciate if someone can just take few minutes and guide me accordingly.

Thanks !

Regards

Comment: i advice you to install a webserver (like xampp) because you need apache also for running PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

and welcome :)

If you're planning on concentrating on PHP more than MySQL, it's a good start to install XAMPP. It's more lightweight and contains both PHP and Mysql. It's better for you to concentrate on learning the basics first, rather than spend time on software components. That's why I would choose XAMPP (or my personal favorite: WAMP Server)

If you'd like to spend a bit more time on database management such as user management, jobs,... it could be interesting to download the Mysql server package from their site.
Also, that package comes with example databases which you can use to learn some SELECT and UPDATE queries. It queries a lot easier that PHPMyAdmin.

If your goal is to use MySQL with self-made applications, get XAMPP and learn some PHP before diving into queries

Comment: Thank you very much for replying. I will go ahead and try out xampp or wamp.

Comment: Also, one more query: If I install any of these packages, so then MySQL will be installed automatically in my system and there is no need to install any MySQL package then ??

Answer (score 0):

> > And then I would want to learn to create web application using php

In this case XAMPP should be your friend. BTW with XAMPP you get an MySQL-Server which is identically with the MySQL standalone. You can fire your querys by using phpmyadmin, or connect via shell (console) or thridparty programms ....

Answer (score 0):

In case that you are using NPM, you can install a standalone version of MySQL using the mysql-server package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql-server